# Playing a simple wav file in iphone ios

Tags: ios, audio

I am trying to play a wav file on click of a button using AudioToolBox framework.There is no error thrown,but the sound is not getting played.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed
{

  NSString *path;
  NSURL *url;
  AVAudioPlayer *player;
  NSLog(@"Hai");
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"];
  url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
  player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
  [player setVolume:5.0];
  [player play];
 }
```

Also tried this code

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"censor-beep-01.wav"];

SystemSoundID soundID;
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
//Use audio sevices to create the sound
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
//Use audio services to play the sound
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Comment: are you trying with simulator?

Comment: declare AVAudioPlayer instance in .h file. It will work

Comment: no i am running from iphone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set AVAudioPlayer framework in header file.. and declare AVAudioPlayer *player; in .h file as

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
synthesize and remove this line in button action AVAudioPlayer *player;
This you should declare in .h file.

Comment: It works fine... Can you please tell what was the problem with my first approach

Comment: player got deallocated right after exiting the method because of ARC optimizations. This thing got me many times.

Comment: Remove retain and use strong in the line @property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;

Comment: As suggested we should use "strong" attribute instead of "assign" in ARC projects.